# How to convert a set of points to a matrix

Tags: octave

I have a matrix, so that each column contains the coordinate of a point. Say I have those points:

```
p1=(1,1)
p2=(1,2)
p3=(2,3)
```

then the matrix would look like that:

```
1 1 0
0 0 1
0 0 0
```

All the coordinates are non-negative, but they are irrational. I multiplied the coordinates by a factor of 10^15 (octave's maximal precision) and passed the matrix to the following function:

```
function MAT = transfer(pairs)
  for i = 1:length(pairs)
      x = round(pairs(i,1));
      y = round(pairs(i,2));
      MAT(x,y) = true;
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, I get an error - subscript indices must be positive integers or logicals. I don't know what the problem is, because I rounded them and they are positive. I would be glad if someone could help me find the problem, or offer an alternative way to do the conversion, I would be grateful.
Shayol

Answer (score 1):

Some of your coordinates could be rounding to zero.  This is one way you will get that error.
I would check to see if any of your values in pairs equal zero after rounding.

Another problem that I see is that you could generate a 10^15 x 10^15 dense matrix.  Instead of the for loop I would recommend using a sparse matrix to generate MAT.  For example

```
MAT = sparse(round(pairs(:, 1)), round(pairs(:, 2)), true(rows(pairs), 1))
```

Comment: I checked, and none of the coordinates  are zero after rounding. I also tried the sparse function, and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, here, is simple. Octave's matrices are stored as vectors. While the single-dimensional indices you are using are within octave's maximal precision, it's a 2D matrix, and the true index of the final entry will be of order 10^30, far too large.

Try using a smaller multiplier. Maybe 10^7, rather than 10^15. You'll probably still run out of space, though, so I'd also suggest using a sparse matrix.